# Corda - How to use token SDK utility functions with Java

Tags: corda

I'm working with the Corda Token SDK within a CorDapp written in Java. I'm having issues with some of the utility functions (ex. "addMoveFungibleTokens").

My worksflows build.gradle has the following dependencies:

```
cordaCompile "$tokens_release_group:tokens-contracts:$tokens_release_version"
cordaCompile "$tokens_release_group:tokens-workflows:$tokens_release_version"
cordaCompile "$tokens_release_group:tokens-money:$tokens_release_version"
```

This allows me to successfully use many of the TokenSDK classes, for instance TokenType, IssueTokensFlow, etc..

However, IntelliJ can't find the class when I try the following import:

```
import com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.move.addMoveFungibleTokens;
```

Looking in external packages, I can see that the .class (MoveTokensUtilitiesKt.class) file is indeed in the JAR, but unlike the other classes in the JAR, this one appears to only have the compiled version as opposed to the source version.

I'm assuming I need to add something to my build.gradle to get this import working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the `MoveTokensUtilities.kt` file (notice that I used the word `file`, and not `class`) from the Tokens SDK, you'll see that it's a collection of functions and not a class (Kotlin allows that).
In order to use it in Java you'd have to suffix it with `kt`.
See example here (from the samples repo):

1. The import: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/dollartohousetoken-TokenSDK/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/dollartohousetoken/flows/HouseSaleInitiatorFlow.java#L7
2. Using one of the functions: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/dollartohousetoken-TokenSDK/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/dollartohousetoken/flows/HouseSaleInitiatorFlow.java#L57

Btw, it's a great example on what you're trying to achieve (written in Java): https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/dollartohousetoken-TokenSDK

Comment: Thanks Adel that was very helpful!